Enviar archivos en servidores de colas de mensajes
En un servidor de colas de mensajes como "Apache Kafka" o "ActiveMQ" o algún otro ¿Se pueden escribir archivos binarios como mensajes?
Mi pregunta es porque siempre me ha tocado usar mensajes de texto, pero ahora tengo la necesidad de que sea un PDF o un Excel. Usaría JMS de java o algún otro protocolo MQ de java.

Actualmente esta pregunta incluye múltiples preguntas en una. Debería centrarse en un solo problema. Haz una pregunta para cada sistema de mensajes, ya que en cada uno podría realizarse de manera distinta.

Si se leer español, solo veo un signo de interrogación que abre y uno que cierra, y el resto solo es contexto del porque la pregunta. No veo que incluya múltiples preguntas en una cuando solo se puede responder "si se puede" o "no se puede",  eso "si comprendo el español".

Si necesitas, podes pasar a base64 tu binario, luego lo recuperas y transformas de String a Binario.
